# TCL filter array results

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

$myList holds the contents of an array via array get.

```
lappend myList array get myArray * * *
puts "$myList"

{636174,736f756e64,30 6d656f77 666f78,736f756e64,30 796969
646f67,736f756e64,30 776f6f66 666f78,736f756e64,31 796970
646f67,736f756e64,31 6261726b 646f67,736f756e64,32 77756666}
```

My end result I am looking for is to gather all entries that are not connected by commas.

> 6d656f77 796969 776f6f66 646f67 6261726b 77756666

If I am to manually hardcode the values using lmap this outputs correctly.

```
% puts [lmap x {636174,736f756e64,30 6d656f77 666f78,736f756e64,30 796969 646f67,736f756e64,30 776f6f66 666f78,736f756e64,31 796970 646f67,736f756e64,31 6261726b 646f67,736f756e64,32 77756666} {if {[string first , $x] != -1} continue {set x}}]
6d656f77 796969 776f6f66 796970 6261726b 77756666
```

If I use the variable $myList this outputs null.

```
puts [lmap x $myList {if {[string first , $x] != -1} continue {set x}}]
```

The same happens with lsearch returning null too.

```
[lsearch -all -inline -not $myList *,*]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your $myList variable only has one element. Use `set` to fill it with the output of `array get myArray`, rather than `lappend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not `lappend`ing properly and instead `lappend`ing a whole list, into another.

```
array set myArray {
    636174,736f756e64,30 6d656f77 666f78,736f756e64,30 796969
    646f67,736f756e64,30 776f6f66 666f78,736f756e64,31 796970
    646f67,736f756e64,31 6261726b 646f67,736f756e64,32 77756666
}
lappend myList [array get myArray]
```

Here, `$myList` contains only one element, which itself then contains the different values. You should expand the list returned by `array get`:

```
lappend myList {*}[array get myArray]
```

That said, to me it looks like all the keys in the array contain commas, and you need the values, so in this case, you might as well skip the `lappend`:

```
set myList [lmap {key val} [array get myArray] {set val}]
# 776f6f66 796969 6d656f77 6261726b 796970 77756666
```